# What does Mr. Outside mean?

Tags: meaning

Could you please let me know what "Mr. Outside" means in the following excerpt.

> Robert Noyce, co-inventor of the integrated circuit (aka the microchip), was the charismatic Mr. Outside, the industry’s ambassador, equally at home at a congressional hearing or buying a round of drinks at the Wagon Wheel.

Note: there is no other context available in the book for this phrase.

Comment: Often in a context where the is a complimentary Mr. Inside who spends their time and focus within an organization actually doing the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195163438.001.0001/acprof-9780195163438-chapter-13

> *Public Startup*, by Leslie Berlin
>
> This chapter recounts Noyce's decision to take a break from his retirement to run SEMATECH, a semiconductor manufacturing consortium supported by the Semiconductor Industry Association (SIA). Noyce expected his work at SEMATECH to resemble the work he had done at Intel. He said that he would be “Mr. Outside”, offering testimony in Washington and speaking around the country about the importance of SEMATECH and its mission. However, he soon realized that there were too many problems within the organization for him to focus exclusively on outside relations.

We see in this quote that "Mr. Outside" refers to the person who goes around networking and building relationships with people external to the organization.